# AWS-SDK Upload to S3 >1GB FILE

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want upload on AWS S3 some huge files (less or more 1 GB).

I'm using this snippet:

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk/clients/all';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const bucketS3 = new S3({
    accessKeyId: 'access_key',
    secretAccessKey: 'secret_key',
    sessionToken: 'security_token',
    region: 'region'
});
const response = await bucketS3.upload({ 
    Bucket: 'my-bucket', 
    Key: 'my-key', 
    Body: fs.createReadStream('my-file.zip') 
}).promise();
```

Is this the correct way for upload a file by stream, without blocking or wasting server resources?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me and will perform concurrent multi-part uploads as needed. Are you seeing any particular problems using this code?

Comment: @jarmod I'm investigating on an Gateway Timeout from Cloudfront when a huge file is uploaded..